# Ways to determine returning "anonymous" guests in PHP

Tags: php

Two types of users visit my website: registered users and guests. Registered users are tracked and retained by PHP session, cookies and individual logins. Guests I find trickier to manage so I give little to no authority to contribute content.

I want to open up editing for users (registered or not) to save favourites, shopping carts, vote in polls, moderate, tag, upload and comment. At the same time, protect the data from other non-registered users.

What are some options or best practices to determine a unique visitor from another and some security measures to consider when allowing them to contribute more? Should I work around their security/restriction settings to provide contribution service or should I expect them to meet in the middle and relax some of their settings to allow cookies etc?

**IP Address** - The IP is an option but only temporary. It can change for a user reconnecting to their Internet with a different IP, and for that matter another user may eventually share the same IP. IP can also be anonymous, shared or misleading.

**PHP Sessions** - OK for a session (and if enabled) but lost on closing the browser.

**Cookies** - Can store session data but is easily (and often) disabled from the client-side.

**Header data** - combining known details of he user might at least group users - ISP, browser, operating system, referring website etc.

**Edit:** I'm still having trouble getting my head around all the the key factors involved... we set up a cookie for a guest. Attach a bunch of edits and user history to that session. If the cookie is removed, the data floats around attached to nothing and the user loses their data. Or if the user logs in, the guest and user data should be merged...

Comment: "Can store session data but is easily (and often) disabled from the client-side." I'd respectfully disagree that an average site visitors even knows what a cookie is.. Unless you're selling used servers or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think cookies would probably be the best option here as it's the only way you are going to be 100% sure requests are unique. Of course, you could possibly add a mix: if cookies are disabled you might be able to try other options of identification such as the IP address method, but that could make it overly-complex.

As you say, IP address is liable to change and in some organizations there may be a group of proxy servers setup which make requests originate from different IPs. Of course, you could check X_FORWARDED_FOR, but they are still liable to change.

Header data is probably going to prove difficult to get good results on I think. If you've got an organization that has the same browser, OS, IP it is going to show people as being the same. Even people not in the same organization may still appear similar (i.e AOL users who get their traffic usually routed through proxy servers, the majority will probably be using the 'AOL browser' that gets shipped with it giving similar headers).

Out of those two options, the IP one is going to be easy to implement but obviously there are the problems I outlined. Checking for unique data in the headers will prove to be absolute pain I think.

Obviously as you say, sessions are lost on closing the browser, and it appears you want the system to behave as if they were a registered user so cookies seem a more obvious choice (especially as you want the 'favourites' to be persistent).

Comment: Related, if you want to go black hat: https://panopticlick.eff.org/ (but I agree, cookies are the answer).

Answer (score 1):

I would just go with sessions.

Your users could change IP addresses (prone to mixup behind NATs and proxies), modify/delete cookies (certainly possible), or change their header (easily through switching browsers).

There is no secure way of identifying a guest if they do not want to be identified. Just go with the standard: cookies/sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use sessions.
Sessions id are stored in a cookie (or for users who doesn't accept cookie, stored in the url with the PHPSID argument)
They won't be erased when the user will close his browser, it just depends on how you set your session/cookies options.
You can set up the timelife of a session to whatever you want, so don't bother with this.
You should also tell to your user about this (enable cookie)
Concerning the data which could be merged when log in, it's your job, to merge it in a proper way, or even ask the user if the option should be saved or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of all of the identifying points that you can find, that are not likely to change, and are likely to be unique - looking at [panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/about) you can gather a bunch of data such as installed fonts and browser plugins. You could take those kinds of more unique data points and hash them to give you an id, and then compare it against the less unique data like useragents and ip addresses.

But honestly, that's super complicated and sneaky. Use cookies/session. If the user doesn't want to enable cookies then they don't want all your anonymous tracking for a reason, and you should honor their decision.