# is it possible to implement remember me in PHP without use of cookies

Tags: php, cookies, remember-me

I was trying to implement remember me functionality in my application.
If we want to implement the remember me functionality in PHP without the use of cookies, then is it possible?
If yes, how?

Comment: If you're talking about remembering a user's login details for subsequent visits, it's not really a task for PHP, but rather for JavaScript. Then you can use local storage or session storage.

Comment: Check out this discussion [Ways to determine returning “anonymous” guests in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874040/ways-to-determine-returning-anonymous-guests-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to implement "remember me" for a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website)

Comment: @Stefan Becker, in this post it's not mentioned that is it possible without using cookies. I mean is there any other way to store user login info except cookies.(Why I am asking this because the user(client-side) can disable cookies then how remember me will work? )